# How to build a job in jenkins when issue is updated in Jira

Tags: jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, jira, build-triggers

We want to make automatic build in Jenkins when issue status is updated in JIRA. Firstly we made Integration between Jira and Jenkins, and we installed the plugin for Jenkins in Jira.
Then we made a configuration for Build trigger in Jenkins - Build when an issue is updated in Jira. We filled this part as it is shown on the first picture.
We set JQL filter and Jira Field Matcher. But we didn't succeed to make an automatic build in Jenkins when an issue changed a status in Jira. 
Could you help us or give an example how to configure the part Parameter mapping (Custom Field and Issue Attribute Path). I send you a screen shots. 
Any information would be useful for us,
Thank you for your support,
Best Regards,
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdzVx.jpg)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05l8g.jpg)

[enter image description here][3]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webhook to perform a REST-call, which can be used to trigger your Jenkins-project.
In your Jenkins-project configuration just enable the option "**Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)**"

As the Authentication Token define a token which will be used by your Jira-webhook. You ned to define the whole server-adress including your token for triggering Jenkins.

And that should be enough to run Jenkins when a ticket has been closed.

Comment: Hi Kim, Thank you for your response, I have already done that. I create a webhook and token and I configure my Jenkins project as you said. But I still could not make an automatic build even my issue in Jira is in status Done. I would be grateful if you could give me some other hint? As I mentioned I need to make an automatic build in Jenkins when the issue in Jira change its status from In Progress to Done.